# ubuntu shell script restart jar

Tags: java, ubuntu-10.04, shell

I need to write a shell script that closes a running .jar and reopens it in terminal.  I've never written a shell script and don't really know where to start.

Here's the command I use to run the app in terminal.

```
java -jar '/home/fdqadmin/NetBeansProjects/dbConvert2/dist/dbConvert2.jar' --Terminal=true
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you by "closing a running .jar"? You're on a Un*x system and hence a "kill -9" is guaranteed to kill the process **AND** release all the resources the process is using (or your Un*x system isn't compliant, but I've never seen one).

So as soon as you send a kill -9, the Java program, all its threads, everything, will be *done*.  No shutdown hook, no nothing.  It's like if you yanked the power cord.

Would a "kill -9" be an acceptable way for you to kill the running Java program?  Will the Java program restart gently after having been "kill -9'ed"?  (It *should* restart nicely, but it's not always the case).

If a real kill is fine and if you know the .jar is always launched using that command line and if you know there shall only be one such .jar launched by the user, you could something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill -9 $(ps aux | grep java | grep dbConvert2 | awk '{print $2}')
java -jar '/home/fdqadmin/NetBeansProjects/dbConvert2/dist/dbConvert2.jar' --Terminal=true
```

You could also go into java-idiosynchratic land and use "smart" command like 'jps' but I'd rather stay with powerful Un*x tools, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that this ain't supposed to be a bullet-proof to use on life-critical systems.  It's just an example of what can be done...

Comment: This system ensures that over 200 employees have the ability to work, is there a 100% surefire method?

Comment: @JustinY17 what SpoonBender is trying to say is that this will stop your process stone cold dead without any warning or anything. I agree with him (+1 by the way) - a better way would be to pass a message somehow to this program so it shuts itself down neatly. Have a script that waits for that to happen then restart it. You might consider something like `monit` or `nagios` to monitor whether this process is executing - if it is killed, these will restart it.

Comment: @Ninefingers: (and the OP) btw I think there's one of the signal you can send using a sigkill that gets correctly caught by Java programs and that you can use to "cleanly" shutdown the app.  So maybe a more advanced script could first send the *I'd-like-you-to-cleanly-shutdown* signal then wait a few seconds then send the *kill -9* if the Java program didn't exit cleanly.  Of course a real monitoring solution like the one you suggested would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

I've commented on here before, but here is an [interesting document](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-signalhandling/) from developerworks on Java Signal handling which might be of interest if you wish to proceed with this method.

I still believe, however, that as in any case of shutting down a process foreign to your current code module, even if you wrote it, is to ask it to stop via one of the many inter-process communication mechanisms.